# Friendly way to read Samsung's built-in Messages app's XML backup

Tags: samsung, backup, sms, samsung-messages

I have an old Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 8. I am using what seems to be the built-in SMS app, called "Messages," the icon is

[image: Messages icon]

I used this app's Backup feature to create an XML file. I uploaded it to my Windows laptop, but when I try to open it, I see raw XML or I get an error message (from Excel and OpenOffice--both Calc and Writer). Calc says "General input/output error." Excel says "This XML file cannot be opened because of an error."

The question is, how can I open this file and get a human-friendly display?

(I suppose I could use a standalone SMS backup/restore app, but I prefer to minimize the contents of my device.)

Thanks!

Comment: Google's official Messaging app is this [Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) and it doesn't have an in-app Backup feature. Looks like it's [Samsung's own Messaging app](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-messages-samsung-messages-rcs/).

Comment: And as for reading the XML: you might try your web browser. At least Firefox usually can render XML, unless it's "heavily customized" (which I wouldn't wonder in case of Samsung).

Comment: Just open the XML file in a text editor like Notepad++. Common XML files don't have information for displaying it in a human friendly way. If your new phone is not one from Samsung it may be better to use a general SMS backup app like [SMS backup & restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) which also has a viewer app: https://sean.lane.sh/SMSViewer/

Comment: @Izzy The web browsers all just render it as text, just like Notepad, so I have to parse it in my head. "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Sounds like I just have to use a third-party app to be able to sort or otherwise work with the backup. Thanks!